# Can't seem to get my asp.net C# table to display

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I haven't done much work with asp.net and the Table class confuses me somewhat.
My aim here is to display a table with a list of volunteers in a database with some columns containing a checkbox or buttons for viewing and editting records. This is what I've got so far...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class VolunteerList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    #region Database
    public OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|database.accdb");
    public OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    public OleDbDataReader rdr;
    #endregion;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            // Check if the user is logged in
            if ((Convert.ToBoolean(Session["Check"]) == false) || Session["Check"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");

        // Display volunteer table
        //volunteers = listVolunteers();
        //volunteers.ID = "volunteerlist";
    }

    protected Table listVolunteers()
    {
        // Query to get volunteer information
        string query = "SELECT gvo_id, gvo_name, gvo_email, gvo_mobile_ph, gvo_dob, gvo_status FROM volunteer";

        // Table will hold the following information on volunteers:
        // ID, Name, Email, Mobile, DOB, Status
        // As well as a check box to do mass delete, a view button and an edit button on each
        Table result = new Table();
        result.ID = "volunteers";

        // Creater table header
        TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow();
        TableHeaderCell id = new TableHeaderCell();
        id.Text = "ID #";
        header.Cells.Add(id);
        TableHeaderCell name = new TableHeaderCell();
        name.Text = "NAME";
        header.Cells.Add(name);
        TableHeaderCell email = new TableHeaderCell();
        email.Text = "EMAIL";
        header.Cells.Add(email);
        TableHeaderCell mobile = new TableHeaderCell();
        mobile.Text = "MOBILE #";
        header.Cells.Add(mobile);
        TableHeaderCell dob = new TableHeaderCell();
        dob.Text = "D.O.B";
        header.Cells.Add(dob);
        TableHeaderCell status = new TableHeaderCell();
        status.Text = "STATUS";
        header.Cells.Add(status);
        TableHeaderCell check = new TableHeaderCell();
        check.Text = " ";
        header.Cells.Add(check);
        TableHeaderCell view = new TableHeaderCell();
        view.Text = " ";
        header.Cells.Add(view);
        TableHeaderCell edit = new TableHeaderCell();
        edit.Text = " ";
        header.Cells.Add(edit);
        // Add header to table
        result.Rows.Add(header);

        //Declaration for following code
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell rid = new TableCell();
        rid.CssClass = "id";
        TableCell rname = new TableCell();
        rname.CssClass = "name";
        TableCell remail = new TableCell();
        remail.CssClass = "email";
        TableCell rmobile = new TableCell();
        rmobile.CssClass = "mobile";
        TableCell rdob = new TableCell();
        rdob.CssClass = "dob";
        TableCell rstatus = new TableCell();
        rstatus.CssClass = "status";
        TableCell rcheck = new TableCell();
        rcheck.CssClass = "check";
        TableCell rview = new TableCell();
        rview.CssClass = "view";
        TableCell redit = new TableCell();
        redit.CssClass = "edit";
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Checked = false;
        Button btnView = new Button();
        btnView.Text = "View";
        Button btnEdit = new Button();
        btnEdit.Text = "Edit";

        // Add volunteers to table
        try
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    rid.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    rname.Text = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    remail.Text = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    rmobile.Text = rdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    rdob.Text = rdr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    rstatus.Text = rdr.GetValue(5).ToString();

                    chk.ID = rid.Text;
                    btnView.PostBackUrl = string.Format("/VolunteerView.aspx?ID={0}", rid.Text);
                    btnEdit.PostBackUrl = string.Format("/VolunteerEdit.aspx?ID={0}", rid.Text);

                    rcheck.Controls.Add(chk);
                    rview.Controls.Add(btnView);
                    redit.Controls.Add(btnEdit);

                    // Add cells to row
                    row.Cells.Add(rid);
                    row.Cells.Add(rname);
                    row.Cells.Add(remail);
                    row.Cells.Add(rmobile);
                    row.Cells.Add(rdob);
                    row.Cells.Add(rstatus);
                    row.Cells.Add(rcheck);
                    row.Cells.Add(rview);
                    row.Cells.Add(redit);

                    // Add row to table
                    result.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TableCell error = new TableCell();
            error.ColumnSpan = 9;
            error.CssClass = "error";
            error.Text = "An error occurred while loading the volunteers";
            row.Cells.Add(error);
            result.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
        }
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is what I have to try and make it post on the .aspx page

```
<form id="list_volunteers" runat="server">
    <% listVolunteers(); %>
</form>
```

I've tried a few things and can't seem to get it to run...

Comment: Try to add to your c# code list_volunteers.Controls.Add(YourTable) after you have filled it

Comment: why don't u just use a grid view and give it a dataTable containing your volunteers as a dataSource

Comment: Please do not mark the question as solved, marking an answer as the answer is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your designer you can take a Placeholder. (The PlaceHolder control is used to reserve space for controls added by code.)

```
<div>
     <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>            
</div>
```

In code behind file you need to add your dynamic table in placeholder.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                      
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(listVolunteers());
}
```

I hope it will help you.